# Bulk edit complex text files

Tags: javascript, php, python, html

**Context:**

I inherited a legacy application consisting of 2.5+ MLOC spread across roughly 2,000 files (PHP 5.5.9, jQuery, HTML currently). Within this codebase are a slough of various security vulnerabilities, code smells, and performance issues. I've been tasked with appeasing infosec and bringing this codebase into the 21st century . I'm using Python to achieve these mass edits.

**Problem:**

I need to edit each of these files and modify the code. I've already tackled the single line edits with basic string comparison.

Here's a typical script structure:

```html
<?php

// some code here

?>

<html><head>
...
</head>
<body>
...
</body>
<script>
...
</script>
</html>
```

I'm at a point now where I need to start modifying whole blocks of HTML, inlined javascript with mixed quotes (both single and double in a single line), and removing methods from scripts.

For example, I have a head section of HTML that looks like this:

```html
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.form.js"></script>

    <title>TITLE</title>
    <!-- TemplateIB -->
    <link rel="Stylesheet" href="../Lib/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.css" />
    <link rel="Stylesheet" href="../Lib/3CLStyle.css" />
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="../Lib/jquery-1.9.1-Combined.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../Lib/jquery.datetimepicker.css" />
    <script src="../Lib/jquery.datetimepicker.full.js"></script>
</head>
```

And I need to modify it to be look like:

```html
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
    <title>TITLE</title>

    <!-- Stylesheets -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../Lib/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../Lib/jquery.datetimepicker.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../Lib/3CLStyle.css" />

    <!-- Boilerplate JS -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../Lib/jquery-1.9.1-Combined.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.form.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../Lib/jquery.datetimepicker.full.js"></script>

    <!-- Custom JS -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/contactHistory.js"></script>
</head>
```

The biggest hurdle here is, the newlines aren't all uniform -- this codebase is over a decade old and has had a lot of hands touch it. So uniformity is non-existent. For example, some files look like:

```html
<head><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
<title>
...
```

And others are like the above examples. Some use tabs for indenting, others use spaces. Lots of variation in how the whitespace was applied.

Another example of another hurdle I see is a situation like this:

```html
<input type="button" class="submit" value="Check History" onclick="CreateHistoryTable()" />
```

And I need to modify it to look like:

```html
<input type="button" class="submit" value="Check History" onclick="createHistoryTable(' <?= $_GET['phone'] ? $_GET['phone'] : ''; ?>', '<?= $_GET['project'] ? $_GET['project'] : ''; ?>' )" />
```

**Potential solutions:**

Like I said, I've already effectively addressed single line edits. For these more complex scenarios I've considered RegEx, but that adds a whole other level of complexity to the already difficult situation.

Based on my reading it looks like [Beautiful Soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) might provide what I need. Can anyone advise on this? Element Tree is another option as well, I just haven't investigated either option deep enough to know if they'll facilitate the restructuring and deep editing I need to do.

Right now, one solution to the whitespacing would be to prettify the HTML, and make it all uniform. It looks like [lxml](https://lxml.de/elementsoup.html) has a good implementation built on Beautiful Soup that doesn't care about whitespacing.

The next step is the block edits -- this is really the biggest hurdle right now. lxml might be key to this, but I've had little luck finding any example code that achieves what I'm trying to do.

I'm not looking for anyone to write the code, I'm just looking for input on how to move forward with these more complex cases. Thank you for any assistance.

Comment: Lot to parse there... might be too broad. Just wanted to give a +1 for Beautiful Soup. Amazing library. Agree, doing initial clean up to create more uniformity is probably worth while.

Comment: Reading a bit more.. how many of these many lines are repeated HTML? Sounds like moving things to a more modern framework, leveraging some layout/templates would eliminate a lot of that. *DRY*

Comment: @ficuscr agreed -- right now I'm still just playing damage control. I have a framework in line, but being developed on PHP 7.1, it won't run on the 5.5.9 servers. Lots of other variables in this process unfortunately, so this effort is simply to get my boss and infosec off my back for now.

Comment: Sounds daunting. Don't underestimate the power of sed and awk. Commit early and often. Good luck!

Comment: But to answer your question, it's sickening how much code (JS, PHP, HTML) is duplicated. By moving to the new framework, I'll eliminate roughly 70% of duplicate code. This codebase is a trainwreck to say the least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, don't write one mega script that does everything in one go.  Write many smaller scripts that fix up a few things.  The smaller ones will be easier to code, debug, and maintain.

Here's a stab at it using BeautifulSoup.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Comment, NavigableString
from collections import defaultdict

html = '''
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.form.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/contactHistory.js"></script>

    <title>TITLE</title>
    <!-- TemplateIB -->
    <link rel="Stylesheet" href="../Lib/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.css" />
    <link rel="Stylesheet" href="../Lib/3CLStyle.css" />
    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="../Lib/jquery-1.9.1-Combined.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../Lib/jquery.datetimepicker.css" />
    <script src="../Lib/jquery.datetimepicker.full.js"></script>
</head>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

# some way to distinguish the js libraries
boilerplate_js = [
    "../Lib/jquery-1.9.1-Combined.min.js",
    "jquery.form.js",
    "../Lib/jquery.datetimepicker.full.js"
 ]

tags = defaultdict(list)

# extract all the tags in the <head>...</head> element and
# put them under various keys in the tags dictionary
for tag in list(soup.html.head):
    if tag.name is not None:
        tag = tag.extract()

        # differentiate 'custom' scripts from 'boilerplate'
        if tag.name == 'script' and tag['src'] not in boilerplate_js:
            tags['custom_js'].append(tag)

        else:
            tags[tag.name].append(tag)

    # comments (and some other things) don't have tag names
    elif isinstance(tag, Comment):
        tags['Comment'].append(tag)

    # elif .... ignoring other possible tags

#create a new <head>...</head> element to be populated below        
new_head = soup.new_tag('head')

# for each kind of tag in the tags dictionary
# we append them to the new_head element
# appending '\n's and ' 's is just for formatting
#obviously, this can be refactored alot
if 'meta' in tags:
    for tag in tags.pop('meta'):
        new_head.append('\n  ')
        new_head.append(tag)

if 'title' in tags:
    new_head.append('\n  ')
    for tag in tags.pop('title'):
        new_head.append('\n  ')
        new_head.append(tag)

if 'link' in tags:
    new_head.append('\n\n  ')
    new_head.append(Comment(' Stylesheets '))
    for tag in tags.pop('link'):
        new_head.append('\n  ')
        new_head.append(tag)

if 'script' in tags:
    new_head.append('\n\n  ')
    new_head.append(Comment(' Boilerplate JS '))
    for tag in tags.pop('script'):
        new_head.append('\n  ')
        new_head.append(tag)

if 'custom_js' in tags:
    new_head.append('\n\n  ')
    new_head.append(Comment(' Custom JS '))
    for tag in tags.pop('custom_js'):
        new_head.append('\n  ')
        new_head.append(tag)

if len(tags):
    new_head.append('\n\n  ')
    new_head.append(Comment(' Other stuff '))
    for key in list(tags.keys()):
        for tag in tags.pop(key):
            new_head.append('\n  ')
            new_head.append(tag)

new_head.append('\n')

soup.html.head.replace_with(new_head)
print(soup)
```

Output:

```
<html><head>
  <meta content="IE=9" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"/>

  <title>TITLE</title>

  <!-- Stylesheets -->
  <link href="../Lib/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.css" rel="Stylesheet"/>
  <link href="../Lib/3CLStyle.css" rel="Stylesheet"/>
  <link href="../Lib/jquery.datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

  <!-- Boilerplate JS -->
  <script src="jquery.form.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script language="JavaScript" src="../Lib/jquery-1.9.1-Combined.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="../Lib/jquery.datetimepicker.full.js"></script>

  <!-- Custom JS -->
  <script src="../js/contactHistory.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

  <!-- Other stuff -->
  <!-- TemplateIB -->
</head>
</html>
```

Comment: Perfect! I totally intend on using different scripts. This is the example I needed to be able to move forward. Thank you for such a direct and useful answer!